# Open syscall failling while debugging in GDB

Tags: gdb

I wanted to run this in GDB while debugging Apache :

```
call open ("/tmp/fifo", 0600)
```

However it fails with -1, I even changed ownership of the file "fifo" to www-data (apache process user) and chmod 777

What could be the problem ? Note that other syscalls are working fine such as call close (0) returning 0

Comment: The second parameter for `open` is usually 0 (read-only) or 1 (write-only) or 2 (read-write). 0600 looks like something one would use as the third parameter to `open` if the second parameter included the O_CREAT (0100) flag.

Comment: I believe the answer you got this code from - [How do I attach a terminal to a detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31830/49439) - is wrong. It should be `call open ("/tmp/fifo", 0)`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for the reply, I did solve the issue and move on before reading your answer, I don't exactly remember how I solved it, but I believe I did call open ("/tmp/fifo", 0, 0600), so 0 was the problem (need to open pipe in read only in the reader as instructed in https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe)